# How to fix watchdog soft lockup cpu# error while installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I was trying to dual-boot ubuntu 18.04 using a bootable usb on my windows 10 pc. My pc uses uefi so made the usb into fat32 type. When I boot with my usb it shows alot of bugs like watchdog soft lockup cpu#x(x = some number). I am using acer nitro 5. Anyone know what this might be.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown, boot from the computer, and immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> is unnecessary.

[image]

The Acer Nitro 5 has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti GPU. When you are in the GRUB menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter editing mode. This will bring up a GNU GRUB screen that looks like this:

[image]

Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to after the string on this screen that starts with `linux`, and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won't remember it in the future. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the `nouveau.modeset=0` option that was added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

Your system should start. After that, open the terminal and run the following commands to install the proprietary graphics driver.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: I am using acer nitro 5 with amd ryzen 2500u and amd radeon RX 560x graphics. And how do I enter the grub.

Comment: I have not installed ubuntu yet on my pc. Its only on the usb drive.

Comment: I replied to your comments by editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I googled alot and found a solution to this. You just have to go into the grub and press "E" while ubuntu is selected and then edit the file. On the line that starts with `linux` just replace `quiet splash` with `noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll` . Hope this works. It worked quiet well for me. After installing ubuntu or while opening it you should go to the boot/grub/grub.cfg file and do the same thing there. Or else you would have to do the same thing everytime the pc starts up.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution to the soft lockup for a long time and the modeset was not the issue. This worked though, I believe it was related to the acpi management somehow not handling power to the cores properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the live boot on a USB drive, you can modify the first menuentry in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg as follows:

```
linux  /caspar/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll ---
```

This allowed me to boot Ubuntu without error.